# generate Hibernate entities from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Is there a tool to generate Hibernate entities from Oracle db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hibernate Tools from JBOSS](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)